# Visualizing generalized basic principle of counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The basic principle of counting states:

> Suppose that two experiments are to be performed. Then if experiment 1 can result in any one of m possible outcomes and if, for each outcome of experiment $\text{1}$, there are n possible outcomes of experiment $\text{2}$, then together there are $mn$ possible outcomes of the two experiments.

this would look like an array: [image]

if we have more than two experiments, then we refer to the generalized basic principle of counting:

> If $r$ experiments that are to be performed are such that the first one may result in any of $n_1$ possible outcomes; and if, for each of these $n_1$ possible outcomes, there are $n_2$ possible outcomes of the second experiment; and if, for each of the possible outcomes of the first two experiments, there are $n_3$ possible outcomes of the third experiment; and if $...$, then there is a total of $n_1 \times n_2 \times n_r$ possible outcomes of the $r$ experiments.

My question is, how do you visualize this generalized version? What would an array of this look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should be $n_1 \times n_2 \times \ldots \times n_r$ instead of $n_1 \times n_2 \times n_r$. As far as visualization goes, it's a hyperbox in dimension $r$, which may not be so comfortable for visualizing. But the product formula should make sense to you if you take it one experiment at a time: After the second experiment there are $n_1 \times n_2$ possibilities, and so if you consider the first two experiments to be a unified experiment and then take the 3rd experiment, you get by the same reasoning that there are $(n_1 \times n_2) \times n_3$ possible outcomes, so if you keep applying the reasoning you get $n_1 \times n_2 \times \ldots \times n_r$ total possible outcomes for the $r$ experiments.

Comment: So if i picture a 3D cube for $r=3$, then the number of possible outcomes is like the volume of the cube? Can i think of this multiplication rule that way? Thanks +1

Comment: Yes you can think of the multiplication that way. And then you can use induction to visualize for higher dimensions, by reducing to dimension $2$ or $3$.

Comment: ok, thanks again. what is it called when you reduce to a lower dimension? I haven't learned that yet and would like to read more about it. thanks.

Comment: @user437158 the basic principle is called induction. You assume that you understand the visualization for dimension $d-1$ and that you can understand the visualization of the product $A \times B$ if you can understand the visualization each $A$ and $B$, and show that then you can rely on $2 \times 2$ reasoning to extend from dimension $d-1$ to $d$ because $B$ is dimension $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of experiments, $r$, is the **dimension** of the array.  For example, for $r = 3$, you want to imagine the values attached to points in a $3$-dimensional grid.  (You can do tricks, like slicing the grid into $2$-dimensional "pages", but this gives one of the three experiments a special significance which you may not want.)

For $r > 3$, it becomes exceedingly difficult to visualize the entire array all at once.

Of crucial importance is the idea of flattening an array, which amounts to turning the array into a list ($1$-dimensional array) by choosing some convention.  Lexicographic ordering is a good one, which looks like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \mapsto \qquad 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}, a_{1,2}, a_{1,3}, a_{2,1}, a_{2,2}, a_{2,3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Iterating this procedure can reduce an array of any size down to any smaller size, but by imposing an arbitrary ordering.

Comment: Ok thanks +1. I didn't know you can reduce an array. Is there a name for reducing an array, so that i can read more about it? Thanks

Comment: The keyword is $\verb|flatten|$, at least in most implementations of the function/method in programming languages.